# IPython cell magic with multiple display object types

Tags: python, ipython, ipython-magic

I would like to create a cell magic in IPython that can return more than one DisplayObject as its result. Specifically, it should return some HTML in the notebook, but I also want a text/python output so that if the notebook is save as Python there will be some plain executable Python code that accomplished the same thing in the resulting script.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can't the magic just return an object of a class that implements [different reprs](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/integrating.html)?

Comment: That's an interesting idea. Let me give it a try.

Comment: For what I need to do, I've realized a custom preprocessor in nbconvert is more appropriate. But I believe your suggestion would work.